# Does PHP's mysqli make it optimized when the same SELECT query is executed several times in a row?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Does PHP's mysqli make it optimized when the same SELECT query is executed several times in a row? I mean does it cache the result set in any way so that the next query just fetches everything from cache?

Comment: Nope. PHP's MySQLi has nothing to do with it. However, MySQL does. Therefore, MySQL might decide it will return a cached version of a SELECT.

Comment: ^^ To clarify, @N.B. means the MySQL _server_ may cache the `SELECT` query

Comment: What mysqli can help with is caching the query plan - for prepared statements, and if you keep the handle.

Comment: Thanx N.B. and Michael Berkowski for instant answers! I need a history log of all previous SELECT statements done by a client. So I have no way to re-execute them elegantly! Nevertheless, big thanx again!

Comment: Thanx, mario. Good tip, but using prepared statements means rewriting all the code!

Comment: Using Prepared Statements will allow you to re-use the same prepared statement with different bind vars, saving the MySQL parser from having to reparse the same SQL statement multiple times